# Change Byte Order in serial comunication, MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab, serial-port

By default, in MATLAB

```
s = serial(serial_port,'BaudRate',3000000,'DataBits',8,'InputBufferSize',80000);
fread(s,s.BytesAvailable,'uint8')
```

Give us LSB first, is it possible to make MSB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option, ByteOrder - bigEndian or littleEndian.
e.g

```
 s = serial(serial_port,'BaudRate',3000000,'DataBits',8,'ByteOrder','bigEndian','InputBufferSize',80000);
```